# How to decrypt TrafficScript encrypted value

Tags: c#, encryption, zeus

We are using TrafficScript running under a Stingray Traffic Manager to encrypt a string and store that encrypted value in a cookie. Like so:

```
$encrypt = "string to encrypt";
$passphrase = "passphrase";
$encrypted= string.base64encode(string.encrypt($encrypt, $passphrase));

http.setResponseCookie("encrypted", $encrypted, "path=/");
```

What I'd then like to do is decrypt that cookie value in C#, however, I've not been able to achieve it thus far. I suspect this is because the exact details of the algorithm used by the TrafficScript isn't documented fully. The reference guide states:

> **string.encrypt( string, passphrase )** - Encrypts a string using the provided pass phrase. The returned string is encrypted using the AES block cipher, using an expanded form of the passphrase as the cipher key. A MAC is also added to ensure the integrity of the string.

I've tried AesManaged but get an exception '*Length of the data to decrypt is invalid*'.

Can anyone provide any pointers?

Comment: can you give me an encrypted base64 string and the passphrase you used?

Comment: Sounds like something you'd have to ask about on the board: http://community.riverbed.com/t5/Answers/bd-p/trafficmanager It looks like it's not documented anywhere.

Comment: Thanks SilverbackNet I'll post on there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to find a way to do this purely with TrafficScript.

So I ended up writing a Java Extension and running that from inside my TrafiicScript rule. It was made possible by reusing some code posted in a blog by [Joseph Ssenyange](http://zenu.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/aes-128bit-cross-platform-java-and-c-encryption-compatibility/) which details how to write cross platform encryption for Java and C#.